# arranging files in a text file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, glob

i have many .txt files in a directory named as (`TU_1.ST01.XXX.TXT_,TU_1.ST02.XXX.TXT_, TU_1.ST03.XXX.TXT_, .......TU_1.ST1000.XXX.TXT_`). i want to arrange all the text files side by side and want to save it in a file which should be equal to the `paste` command in shell scripting.

Can anybody help me doing this.

I tried the script

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

for file in glob.glob("*.TXT_"):
    print(file)
    #here i want to arrange files
```

Comment: You mean..Copy all *.TXT files in a directory ? What is side by side ?

Comment: paste .TXT files to a file

Comment: i think this can be done using numpy.zip @PySaad

Comment: Recommend shutil package. To copy and past directory, 
shutil.copytree("source dir", "destination dir")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example input files:

```
$ paste *.txt
one    four    six
two    five    seven
thee           eight   
               nine
```

Using `pandas` is one option.

```
import pandas  as pd
from   pathlib import Path

>>> pd.DataFrame(f.read_text().splitlines() for f in Path().glob('*.txt'))
      0      1      2     3
0   one    two   thee  None
1  four   five   None  None
2   six  seven  eight  nine
```

You can then `.tranpose()` / `.T` to turn each file into its own column.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(f.read_text().splitlines() for f in Path().glob('*.txt'))
>>> df.T
      0     1      2
0   one  four    six
1   two  five  seven
2  thee  None  eight
3  None  None   nine
```

You can then use `.to_csv()` and set the `sep` if you want to emulate the tabbed output from `paste`

```
>>> print(df.T.to_csv(index=None, header=None, sep='\t'), end='')
one    four    six
two    five    seven
thee           eight   
               nine
```

You could also implement it using `itertools.zip_longest`

Comment: how to save it to a ascii file with tab separation

Comment: can you please suggest how to use itertools.zip_longest for more files